# Javascript and XML

Tags: javascript, xml

I am working on JavaScript using HTML5 and I am stuck with a certain aspect. I want to do the following:

1. Create a table using JavaScript (which is fairly easy)
2. Extract details from a XML file that is available online
3. Enter the values in the table

For example, the linkhttp://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/cycle-hire/livecyclehireupdates.xml contains the information for cycle availability at each station 
 1. I need to create a table with two columns. One for 'Station Name' and the other for 'No of cycles available'
 2. I need to write code that only takes in the above link as input and extracts values of 'Name' and 'nbEmptyDocks'.

Ex : `<name> ABC,Surrey </name> <nbEmptyDocks> 10  </nbEmptyDocks>`, how will I extract the values ABC,Surrey and 10 and place them in respective columns?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script language= "JavaScript">
document.write('<br> <br><table width="50%" border="1">'); document.write('<th> Dock Station');
document.write('<th> Number of Cycles');
document.write('<br> <br><table width="50%" border="1">');  
var Connect = new XMLHttpRequest();
Connect.open("GET", "http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/feeds/cycle-hire/livecyclehireupdates.xml", false);
Connect.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
Connect.send(null); 
var TheDocument = Connect.responseXML; 
var station = TheDocument.childNodes[0];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
var stations = station.children[i];
var name = stations.getElementsByTagName("name");
var avail = Customer.getElementsByTagName("nbEmptyDocks");
document.write("<tr><td>");
document.write( name[0].textContent.toString());
document.write("</td><td>");
document.write(avail[0].textContent.toString());
document.write("</td>");   
document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write (" </table>");
</script>
</body></html>
```

On further reading, I understood that the above code might not work for Chrome, and I need one that works with chrome.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
var xmlDoc;
var xmlloaded = false;

function initLibrary()
{
importXML("http:///www.somedomain.com/somesubdir/somefile.xml");
}

function importXML(xmlfile)
{
try
{
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", xmlfile, false);
}
catch (Exception)
{
var ie = (typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined');
if (ie)
{
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;
while(xmlDoc.readyState != 4) {};
xmlDoc.load(xmlfile);
readXML();
xmlloaded = true;
}
else
{
xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
xmlDoc.onload = readXML;
xmlDoc.load(xmlfile);
xmlloaded = true;
}
}

if (!xmlloaded)
{
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
xmlhttp.send("");
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
readXML();
xmlloaded = true;
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But this doesnt seem to work either

Comment: And how far have you gotten in the javascript? We won't write it for you from scratch

Comment: You likely can't do what you want with just Javascript, unless your site hosts that xml file, because of the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: @Johan I have added the code, how much ever I could do, to the question

Comment: @user3297662: Where did you get that `station`, `stations`, `<name>`, `Customer` and `<nbEmtpyDocks>` from? None of it appears in the BBC xml. Also your url is wrong, or is that your proxy?

Comment: @Bergi I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy). Do you at least know how to select the required nodes oncy you have loaded the `xmlDoc`?

Comment: @Bergi - I think I can get that part done as I read quite many articles on it. I havent tried that yet because I cldn't load the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Google API for grabbing RSS and rending it on your page: you can get started [here.](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/)

Answer (score 0):

As you say they are not tags themselves, for which it would've been fairly trivial to access them via DOM methods.

Instead, you will need to grab the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) of the `<title>` and/or `<description>` nodes in each `<item>`. Once you have done that, you will need to do a little string processing. However, the strings are quite predictable, so this is easy:

```
var text = "Max Temp: 8°C (46°F), Min Temp: 5°C (41°F), Wind Direction: SW, Wind Speed: 8mph, Visibility: good, Pressure: 1002mb, Humidity: 92%, Pollution: n/a, Sunrise: 08:13GMT, Sunset: 16:40GMT";

var pairs = text.split(", "),
    info = {};
for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
    var pair = pairs[i].split(": ");
    info[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
console.log(info)
// {"Max Temp":"8°C (46°F)","Min Temp":"5°C (41°F)","Wind Direction":"SW","Wind Speed":"8mph","Visibility":"good","Pressure":"1002mb","Humidity":"92%","Pollution":"n/a","Sunrise":"08:13GMT","Sunset":"16:40GMT"}
console.log(info["Max Temp"], info["Min Temp"])
// "8°C (46°F)", "5°C (41°F)"
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understood that completely. Let me try explaining my doubt again. <br>

Comment: Let me try explaining my doubt again. <br> Suppose I need to create a table with two columns "Station Name" and "Number of Bikes". The XML is obtained from a link - eq: www.xyz.uk/update/source.xml and the sample XML file is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stations><station><name> ABC </name><nbBikes>12</nbBikes><nbEmptyDocks>7</nbEmptyDocks></station> <br> <br> The code that should access the link ( WITHOUT including the xml file in my code) and from that link it will obtain the station name  (from tag 'name') no.of bikes ( from tag 'nbBikes') and enter to respective columns in table